# Accessing contacts using carddav protocol from yahoo or any other web mail server

Tags: .net, api, carddav

I wanted to retrieve contacts from Yahoo or any third party CARDDAV supported mail servers using CARDDAV protocol. I found the .NET Code to retrieve the contacts using CARDDAV on the link https://github.com/Metric/CardDavNet. I am trying to get the Yahoo and Google contacts using the URI:

https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/userEmail/lists/default

I made some requests using PROPFIND but getting empty address book. I think I am quite close but may be missing something.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code of CardDavNet I don't think that it implements the OAuth authentication parts. Which is now required to connect to Google CardDAV ([Google’s CardDAV requires OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/carddav/#googles_carddav_requires_oauth_20)).

I don't know whether you can use BasicAuth with Yahoo's implementation, but it may work with iCloud.